# In Bash, what is an efficient way to append integers to file or directory names to avoid duplicates?

Tags: bash, variables, append

I have a small function that can be used to move objects to a trash directory:

```
trash(){
    object="${1}"
    directoryTrashWithTildePrefix="~/trash"
    eval directoryTrash="${directoryTrashWithTildePrefix}"
    if [ -z "${object}" ]; then
        echo "object not specified"
        return
    fi
    # If the trash directory does not exist, create it.
    mkdir -p "${directoryTrash}"
    # Move the object to trash.
    echo "moving "${object}" to "${directoryTrashWithTildePrefix}""
    # Move the object in a way appropriate to its type (file or directory).
    if [ -f "${object}" ]; then
        mv "${object}" "${directoryTrash}"
   elif [ -d "${object}" ]; then
        mv "${object}" "${directoryTrash}"
    else
        echo ""${object}" not file or directory"
        return
    fi
}
```

Is there an efficient, sensible way to append integers to the objects' names automatically in order to avoid duplicate names in the trash directory?

Comment: The answers to [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35818/29165) code golf question are likely useful here. ([Here's mine.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35930/29165))

Comment: You can avoid the `eval` by simply using `$HOME` instead of `~`: `directoryTrash="$HOME/trash"`

Comment: @MarkReed or putting the tilde outside of the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timestamp, for instance:
myObject=obj_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`

```
[oriz@ lib git:master]$ myObject=obj_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
[oriz@ lib git:master]$ echo $myObject
obj_20141105_201843
[oriz@ lib git:master]$ myObject=obj_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
[oriz@ lib git:master]$ echo $myObject
obj_20141105_201847
```

Comment: Then you can use nanosecond accuracy for the date with: $ myObject=obj_$(date +%s%N)